# MouseWheel event continues firing after scrolling has stopped

Tags: c#

```
void Component_MouseWheel(Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    LongTimeExecutionMethod();
}
```

If I scroll a long time and stop, the event continues firing.  How can I stop the event firing when scrolling stops?

I tried this, but it does not work:

```
void component_MouseWheel(Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    component.MouseWheel -= component_MouseWheel;
    LongTimeExecutionMethod();
    component.MouseWheel += component_MouseWheel;
}
```

Comment: I believe your LongTimeExecution method hangs the thread and after it stops executing, all mouse wheel events are sent to the thread that actually happened while it was executing. Did you try commenting out your LongTimeExecutionMethod?

Comment: in your second function, you could try putting `Application.DoEvents();` before reassigning the event handler. that should clear the queue (afaik).

Comment: @Legoless, probably I misunderstood you. That will I receive from commenting out LongTimeExecutionMethod? Event will fire, but will do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This might sound like a 101 kind of thing to say, but when I was using a the mouse scroll in a game I made, this exact happened to me and it ended up being the mouse. Have you tried a different mouse?

Comment: ah ok. and are you saying to @legoless that you KNOW the method fires but will do nothing if you comment out that line or that you've tried and it does?